# UITableViewCell and label not displaying text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a cell that has two labels in it. The table view is linked to the dataSource and delegate, the labels in the cell are linked to an IBOutlet, what not. It looks to me like this should work, but this code below is not running so the Cell or labels are not populated with text. Any ideas? Or anything I'm missing?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"theLabelCell";
CustomClassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

CustomClassText *customText = _arrayThatHasText[indexPath.row];


if (![self isSelectionMode]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

cell.TitleLabel.text = customText.firstLabel;
cell.TextLabel.text = customText.secondLabel;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to also register the cell identifier for reuse?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomClassCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"theLabelCell"];
}
```

Comment: I did but still not difference

Answer (score 1):

If you are not seeing any cells, then check whether `numberofSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate methods are not returning 0

Comment: hmm. Interesting. Is returning 0

Comment: It should == [_arrayThatHasText count]

Comment: sorry I meant that _arrayThatHasText is returning zero, which is the weird part

Answer (score 1):

When does your `_arrayThatHasText` get populated? The issue might very well be that the data source (`_arrayThatHasText`) is getting instantiated before the `numberofSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate methods are being called and then after these methods are called the data source is being populated with actual data -> which would result in the 0 values in the delegate methods as you are experiencing.

You might want to try putting a `[self.tableView reloadData]` call at the end of `ViewWillAppear` or in `ViewDidAppear` method and see if that helps.